# "onPreferenceStartFragment()" method not being called when Preference is clicked on

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, androidx

Migrating to AndroidX, I have a Preference Screen with different preferences for a user to click. The ultimate goal for this is, when a user clicks a preference it brings them to a new screen. The new screen will extend PreferenceFragmentCompat according to what the Google advocates. Linking the screens together I have declared "app:fragment" in my XML.

When the user taps a preference with an associated fragment the interface method 
PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferencesStartFragmentCallback.onPreferenceStartFragment() is called.This method is where you should handle displaying the new screen and should be implemented in the surrounding Activity.

The onPreferenceStartFragment method is never being called, and the screen is never inflated. I've added some code below.

I've tried adding dependencies to the gradle that might have been missing to resolve the issue.

'''

preference.xml

```
    <PreferenceCategory
            android:key="@string/aboutPreferencesCategory"
            android:title="@string/settings_aboutPreferencesCategoryTitle">

            <Preference
                android:id="@+id/about_preference_screen"
                android:key="@string/aboutPreferenceKey"
                android:layout="@layout/preference_main"
                app:fragment="com.fitnesskeeper.****.About****Fragment"
                android:title="@string/settings_aboutTitle"/> 
    '''



SettingsActivity.java extends AppCompatActivity implements PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback

     @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceStartFragment(PreferenceFragmentCompat caller, androidx.preference.Preference pref) {

            // Instantiate the new Fragment
            final Bundle args = pref.getExtras();
            final Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentFactory().instantiate(getClassLoader(), pref.getFragment(),args);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment.setTargetFragment(caller, 0);

            // Replace the existing Fragment with the new Fragment
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
    } 

'''

AboutFragment.java extends PreferenceFragmentCompat


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_runkeeper,container,false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

'''

grade(module app)



      implementation('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2')
        implementation ('androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0')
        implementation('androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0')
        implementation('androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0')
        implementation('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0')
        implementation('androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0')
        implementation('androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0')
        implementation('androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha01')
        implementation('com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0')
        implementation('androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0')
        implementation('androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0')
        implementation('androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0')

'''

I have a breakpoint on the onPreferenceStartFragment but the breakpoint is x'd out and not checking off as green. My boss told me, that means the method would never be executed.
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback is handled by OnPreferenceTreeClick(). If you override it without calling its super version it won't work.